# Multiple cascaded dropdown in angular, once selected the datasource of all dropdown should update

Tags: javascript, html, angular

App.Component.html Code
Added 4 dropdowns cascaded.
bind  with static countries data

```
<div class="card-container">
      <div class="card card-small" >
      A: <select id="sel1" (change)="ChangeSelect($event.target.value,1)" >
        <option *ngFor="let option of GetData(1)" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.value}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card card-small" >
      B: <select id="sel2" (change)="ChangeSelect($event.target.value,2)" >
        <option *ngFor="let option of GetData(2)" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.value}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card card-small" >
      C: <select id="sel3" (change)="ChangeSelect($event.target.value,3)" >
        <option *ngFor="let option of GetData(3)" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.value}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card card-small" >
      D: <select id="sel4" (change)="ChangeSelect($event.target.value,4)" >
        <option *ngFor="let option of GetData(4)" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.value}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Afte rendering data
this is the typescript code
had to add as StackOverflow won't let me add my code
what a pity.
App.component.ts Typescript code
I am not able to fix the issue as any selected value in the dropdown should be updated throughout all the cascade dropdown

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'my-select-proj';
  public dataArr = new DataArr();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
  }
  loadData() {
    var arr = new Array<string>("-Select-", "India", "USA", "JAPAN", "UK", "RUSSIA", "CANADA");
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
      const countryName = arr[index];
      var dataItem = new DataItem();
      dataItem.value = countryName;
      dataItem.isUsed = false;
      dataItem.Selected = false;
      this.dataArr.col1.push({ ...dataItem });// clone
      this.dataArr.col2.push({ ...dataItem });
      this.dataArr.col3.push({ ...dataItem });
      this.dataArr.col4.push({ ...dataItem });
    }
  }
  SetOther(value, indexArr) {
    console.log("VAL::" + value);
    console.log("ARR::" + indexArr);

    for (let index = 0; index < indexArr.length; index++) {//2,3,4
      const element = indexArr[index];
      var itemArray = this.dataArr['col' + element];
      var itm = itemArray.filter(x => x.value == value);//set index
      if (itm && itm.length) {
        itm[0].isUsed = true;
        itm[0].Selected = false;
      }
    }
  }

  ChangeSelect(event, index) {
    var prevSelVal = this.dataArr.col1.filter(x => x.Selected && x.value != event);
    var itemArray = this.dataArr['col' + index];
    itemArray.filter(x => x.Selected && x.value != event)
      .forEach((x) => { x.Selected = false; x.isUsed = false; });//previous selected ? then reset

    var idx = itemArray.findIndex(x => x.value == event);//set index
    for (let index = 0; index < itemArray.length; index++) {
      if (index === idx) {
        itemArray[idx].isUsed = true;//set al false
        itemArray[idx].Selected = true;//set al false
      }
    }
    var mainArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const remIndex = mainArr.indexOf(index, 0);
    if (remIndex > -1) {
      mainArr.splice(remIndex, 1);
    }
    this.SetOther(event, mainArr);
  }
  GetData(index) {
    console.log("I:" + index);
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        console.log("I-Data:" + JSON.stringify([...this.dataArr.col1.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col1.filter(x => x.Selected)]));
        return [...this.dataArr.col1.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col1.filter(x => x.Selected)]
        break;
      case 2:
        console.log("I-Data:" + JSON.stringify([...this.dataArr.col2.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col2.filter(x => x.Selected)]));
        return [...this.dataArr.col2.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col2.filter(x => x.Selected)]
        break;
      case 3:
        console.log("I-Data:" + JSON.stringify( [...this.dataArr.col3.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col3.filter(x => x.Selected)]));
        return [...this.dataArr.col3.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col3.filter(x => x.Selected)]
        break;
      case 4:
        console.log("I-Data:" + JSON.stringify([...this.dataArr.col4.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col4.filter(x => x.Selected)]));
        return [...this.dataArr.col4.filter(x => !x.isUsed), ...this.dataArr.col4.filter(x => x.Selected)]
        break;
    }
  }
}

export class DataArr {
  public col1: Array<DataItem> = [];
  public col2: Array<DataItem> = [];
  public col3: Array<DataItem> = [];
  public col4: Array<DataItem> = [];
}
export class DataItem {
  public value: string = "";
  public isUsed: boolean = false;
  public Selected: boolean = false;
}
```

I am not able to fix the issue as any selected value in the dropdown should be updated throughout all the cascade dropdown

Comment: https://shazwazza.com/post/tsql-case-statement-in-where-clause-for-not-in-or-in-filter/